# Application testing on jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am testing my application on jmeter but after we run the test the login is unsuccessful so how i can i extract the request verification token with single user so that i can login and test the application .[image]

Comment: Can you share the requests and data that a regular login through a browser (or other means)?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case the location of the Regular Expression Extractor is not correct, according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) it's being applied to all samplers, make sure that this is something you want.

In general [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) instead it allows using [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for getting the data from HTML documents in more easy/robust/readable way, the relevant configuration would be:

[image]